# Relacionar entidade com mais de um entidade

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Olá, possuo em meu sistema as seguintes entidades Cliente, Fornecedor e Financeira. Todas elas possuem uma lista de Contatos, como ficaria um relacionamento bidirecional nestes moldes.

```
public class Client {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Contact> contacts
}

public class Supplier {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Contatc> contacts
}

public class Financial {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Contat> contacts
}

public class Contact {
    @ManyToOne
    ?????????
}
```

Estou utilizando Hibernate como ORM e SpringMVC.
Desde já agradeço.

EDIT: Seria mais ou menos isso que preciso, achei este exemplo e vou estudar como usar por que não conhecia, mas parece me resolver o problema.

http://www.javabeat.net/polymorphic-association-mapping-relationship-hibernate/

Comment: Nâo precisa de anotaçao na class Contact

Comment: Iria precisar porque preciso que seja bidirecional entendeu. Pelo menos penso assim.

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo de bidirecional:

```
public class User {
    private int     id;
    private String  name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "groupId")
    private Group   group;
}
public class Group {
    private int         id;
    private String      name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="group")
    private List<User>  users;
}
```

Segue o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5360795) do SOen que tirei o exemplo, e lá contem uma explicação sobrea as diferenças entre unidirecional e bidirecional;

Comment: Rafael eu entendo as diferenças, acho que me expliquei mal na pergunta. Na verdade eu acho que preciso de um mapeamento polimorfico da entidade Contato. Pensei em usar @AnyMetaDef mas nunca usei então fico em dúvida em usar ou não. De qualquer forma o texto e bem esclarecedor e acabou sanando outras duvidas minha. Achei este exemplo (http://www.javabeat.net/polymorphic-association-mapping-relationship-hibernate/)